# I want to get all dates between two dates excluding weekends in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to print all dates between a start_date and end_date, which exclude weekends (sat,sun).
I want jquery code.

I am able to calculate no of days between two dates excluding weekends but dont know how to get all dates.

i have tried this code.

```
function getBusinessDateCount (startDate, endDate) {
    var elapsed, daysBeforeFirstSaturday, daysAfterLastSunday;
    var ifThen = function (a, b, c) {
        return a == b ? c : a;
    };

    elapsed = endDate - startDate;
    elapsed /= 86400000;

    daysBeforeFirstSunday = (7 - startDate.getDay()) % 7;
    daysAfterLastSunday = endDate.getDay();

    elapsed -= (daysBeforeFirstSunday + daysAfterLastSunday);
    elapsed = (elapsed / 7) * 5;
    elapsed += ifThen(daysBeforeFirstSunday - 1, -1, 0) + ifThen(daysAfterLastSunday, 6, 5);

    return Math.ceil(elapsed);
}
```

This is giving me no of days without weekend, suppose i select date from Fri to Mon, then only 2 days will be given.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: As a side note, you should avoid using 86400000 when calculating dates as doing this means that your code won't account for Daylight Savings (i.e. when there is one less, or more, hour(s) on the day the clocks change.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below code will iterate across all days in a given time frame and push the dates to an array if the day isn't a Saturday or Sunday. It doesn't account for public holidays and uses Vanilla JS (no jQuery needed.)

As you can see, I use `.getDay()` to determine whether what day of the week a given date is and check that it doesn't equal 6 (Saturday) or 0 (Sunday).

I then push it to the `dates` array to be used as you see fit. The reason I use `.push(new Date(current))` instead of simply `.push(current)` is because the `.setDate` function replaces the value that variable points to and would result in an array full of the same date x amount of times without it.

The `current` variable could be removed altogether and the code changed to use the `start` variable but I like to create a new one just for readability.

```
const getBusinessDays = (startDate, endDate) => {
  const start = new Date(startDate);
  const end = new Date(endDate);
  const current = new Date(startDate);
  const dates = [];

  while (current <= end) {
    if (current.getDay() !== 6 && current.getDay() !== 0) {
      dates.push(new Date(current));
    }

    current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1);
  }

  return dates;
}

const businessDays = getBusinessDays('10-01-2019', '11-29-2019');

console.log(businessDays);
```

Comment: Thank you, i have checked it. It is working fine.